# How can I add splash screen I my flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I was going through various articles about adding splash screen to the app . I want to  create splash screen through the splash screen package also other methods are welcome but I am not able to figure out where and how to put out the code for adding the splash screen I am a beginner in flutter and dart. I have attached the required code below:-

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserInfo();
  }

  Future getUserInfo() async {
    await getUser();
    setState(() {});
    print(uid);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Login',

      home: (uid!=null && authSignedIn != false) ? FirstScreen() : LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

bool authSignedIn;
String uid;
String name;
String imageUrl;
Future getUser() async {
  // Initialize Firebase
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool authSignedIn = prefs.getBool('auth') ?? false;

  final User user = _auth.currentUser;

  if (authSignedIn == true) {
    if (user != null) {
      uid = user.uid;
      name = user.displayName;

      imageUrl = user.photoURL;
    }
  }
}

Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  // Initialize Firebase
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final User user = userCredential.user;

  if (user != null) {
    // Checking if email and name is null
    assert(user.uid != null);

    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(user.photoURL != null);

    uid = user.uid;
    name = user.displayName;

    imageUrl = user.photoURL;

    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final User currentUser = _auth.currentUser;
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('auth', true);

    return 'Google sign in successful, User UID: ${user.uid}';
  }

  return null;
}

void signOutGoogle() async {
  await googleSignIn.signOut();
  await _auth.signOut();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool('auth', false);

  uid = null;
  name = null;

  imageUrl = null;

  print("User signed out of Google account");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods I know about splash screen the native one and the non native :

In this answer I will give you the non native  solution without using a plugin :

Splash Screen is a view where you can do all what you want with flutter widgets :
You can create your view then add it in main.dart `home: SplashScreen();`
->Show that SplashScreen for (3,5 secs) and then do a pushReplacement navigation to your first view :
This an example of Splash Screen :

[image]

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _SplashPageState();
}

class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5),
        () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "TabsRoute"));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 144,
              height: 144,
              child: Image.asset("images/logo.png"),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                "Company Name",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Implementation in main.dart :

```
  
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:base_project/pages/TabsPage.dart';
import 'package:base_project/pages/SplashPage.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
   routes: {
     'TabsRoute':(context)=>TabsPage(),
   },
    home: SplashPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Full Application Example here on Github : https://github.com/HoussemTN/flutter_base_project

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other comments there are two methods. The native and the non native, but I would recommend the native since the non native takes few split seconds to pop up and takes more if you're using the debug apk. Of course you don't want the user to look at that black screen even for a split second. The method is a little tricky cue you have to go through your config files.

I'll go with an example in one of my projects and I'm only showing the android one because I've never tried the IOS solution.

in your project folder tree you go to

```
your_project_name/android/app/src/main/res/
```

[image]
the folders inside the rectangular area are your workspace for this operation.
all the things you're going to edit are XML files and you only have to do few touches and you're done.

choose the image you want to see in the splash screen and make sure it's around 100 px give or take so that you can see it if it's too big it will be rendered but you'll see parts. And also make sure the name doesn't contain any special characters or capital letters or spaces just make it simple like `splash_screen` and don't add the picture format extension like `*.png / *.jpeg` just the name. Then put it in the `drawable` folder you have in your project. Then go to `drawable-v21` and go to `launch_background.xml` like in the picture below and uncomment that commented section

[image]

You'll make two changes in this file. First change that ic_launcher to your picture/icon name, which in our case is `splash_screen` and add a line specifying the background color of the screen.

```
<item android:drawable="@color/teal" />
```

note: `teal` here is the name I chose for my color

The final result should look like this:

[image]

Now you only have one last thing to do which is defining that color in xml format which is why I mentioned before that we'll use the values folder as well.

Go to your `values` folder and create a new XML file called `colors.xml` and put inside it this XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="teal">#009688</color>
</resources>
```

like this

[image]

of course you'll need to change the color name and the color hex value.

And VOILA!

I know this is probably a late answer and and a long one, if it doesn't help you right now maybe it'll help somebody in need in the future.